# ValueError: Error when checking input: expected lstm_1_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (378, 20)

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to fit my 2d array to LSTM, since LSTM takes 3d input I can't figure out how to do that. my .csv file has 21 cols, 1st one is instance number, last one is string type Class label. rest are feature list. csv file shape (540, 20).

I have tried expanding dimension to 3d with np.expand_dims, I am getting error like ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 10800 into shape (378,1,20).

```
file = ("training_mfcc.csv")

cols = np.arange(21); 
cols  = [str(x) for x in cols]
cols[20]='Class'
dataset = pd.read_csv(file,header=None,names = cols)

# ---------------------------
# Preprocessing. i.e convert categorical to numeric
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder 
dataset['Class'] = LabelEncoder().fit_transform(dataset['Class'])

train,test=train_test_split(dataset,test_size=0.3,random_state=36,stratify=dataset['Class'])
X_train=train.drop('Class',axis=1)
Y_train=train['Class']
X_test=test.drop('Class',axis=1)
Y_test=test['Class']
X=dataset.drop('Class',axis=1)
Y=dataset['Class']


num_classes = len(set(Y))



X = np.array(X)
X = X.astype('float64')
X /= 255

Y = np.array(Y)
Y = Y.astype('float64')
Y_train = to_categorical(Y_train, num_classes)
Y_test = to_categorical(Y_test, num_classes)
Y = to_categorical(Y, num_classes)

print(X.shape)
X = X.reshape(X.shape[0],1, X.shape[1])
Y = Y.reshape(Y.shape[0],1, num_classes)


num_classes = 5
data_dim = 20
timesteps = 1
batch_size = 12




model = Sequential()
# model.add(Embedding(45, 15, input_length = (X.shape[1], 1), dropout = 0.3))

model.add(LSTM(32, return_sequences=True, stateful=True, batch_input_shape=(batch_size, timesteps, data_dim)))
model.add(LSTM(32, return_sequences=True, stateful=True))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
# model.add(Flatten())
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'], early_stop = EarlyStopping(monitor='loss', patience=2))

model.summary()

model.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size =batch_size, epochs = 100, 
          verbose = 1, validation_data=(X_test, Y_test))
```

I expect code to adjust dynamically and get reshaped by the file's instances and model.fit should give no errors.

Comment: I think the problem is that you are reshaping the wrong array (X vs X_train/X_test).

Comment: Can you suggest the edit in the existing code?